# VMware Installation Error

Tags: windows-7, installation, vmware-workstation

I recently installed Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate. I wanted to install VMware Workstation 10.0.1 and it won't install. After clicking install it pop's up a dialog box of error, seen below.

[image: screenshot of the error dialog]